# Reddit PRAW bot posting with my main account and not the bot

Tags: python, praw

I'm able to post images using python PRAW but it's only posting from my user account and not the bot.

```
reddit = praw.Reddit(
        client_id=secret.client_id,
        client_secret=secret.client_secret,
        password=secret.password,
        user_agent="my user agent",
        username=secret.username,
    )
    print(reddit.user.me())

sub_title = sub_title
title = title
reddit.subreddit(sub_title).submit_image(title, image_path=pic)
```

This is the instance I created
the password and username is my account's

I tried changing the username to the name of the bot but it failed authentication.